# How to center align a button using bootstrap?

Tags: css, html, button, bootstrap-4

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Gallary</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm new to html and bootstrap. I'm trying to place a button in the center of the webpage vertically and horizontally. I have created a container and added a row inside it. Inside the row I offsetted a 4 column div element. Inside the div element is the button. But this button does'nt seem to be in the center. If I add a second button and tried offsetting it, it would be placed in the center but the hover wont work(or button does'nt work).

Comment: please add your code here.

Answer (score 2):

In Bootstrap 4 you should use the text-center class to align inline-blocks.

NOTE: text-align:center; defined in a custom class you apply to your parent element will work regardless of the Bootstrap version you are using. And that's exactly what .text-center applies.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">    
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col text-center">
      <button class="btn btn-default">Centered button</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As described in the official **[Bootstrap Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/text/)**, you can just add the class name `text-center` to a parent class list to horizontally center it's children text elements using `text-align: center`.

---

Check and run the following **Code Snippet** for a practical example of using the `text-center` class name:

```css
/* CSS */

a {text-decoration: none;}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 text-center">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary"><a href="#linkToYourOtherPage">Gallary</a></button>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This positions the button perfectly for me. But the button doesn't seem to work in google chrome. No redirecting, hover, or cursor. It works while running code snippet.

Comment: Hmm.... That's weird. Do you need the button to redirect you to a link?

Comment: I just need it as a button to take me to the next page.

Comment: Then you need to nest an anchor tag inside the button. Let me update the answer.

Comment: Check the updated code snippet.

Comment: Still it's the same. Button doesn't react to the cursor.

Comment: Can you post the exact code in jsfiddle.net and give me the link. Ill check it out.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tjsw7r2p/#&togetherjs=9fslTNNhMS

Comment: This code runs perfectly in jsfiddle and code snippet but not in the google chrome. In chrome the button just doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There is a class 'text-center' already with the property of text-align: center in bootstrap. You should use that in the parent element in order to center align child elements.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 text-center">
      <button class="btn btn-default">Gallery</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```